# What set is this?

Tags: set-identification

I picked these up at a local thrift store, all in their original packaging. Hoping it’s a complete set.

Number on it says: 135149
No real unique bricks to report and there are no bag numbers on it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look like bags from [Bricks and Animals (11011-1)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/11011-1/bricks-and-animals/?inventory=1):

[image: Box photo]

[image: Set parts photo]

If those are the only bags you have, it isn't complete, but you may still be able to build some of the models. The bags are sorted by color, and some of the models appear to use the colors that you have.

[image: Models]

The [instructions are available via Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/sets/11011-1/bricks-and-animals/?inventory=1#bi).

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! I just confirmed a few of the more unique pieces, and they are all in that set. My son is going to be super excited.